# Why are not clojure namespaces in MVCC?

Tags: clojure

There's a lot of discussion on how to best tender the namespaces. Stuart Sierra enlightens us all about this in his [Lifecycle Composition](http://stuartsierra.com/2013/09/15/lifecycle-composition) and the work with [clojure.tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace).

Most of the complexity comes from the mutability of the namespaces; then why don't we put the namespaces in Clojures own MVCC? There must be a reason to why, but I cannot figure it out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One practical reason is that **namespaces are used to build the MVCC** so it makes building the compiler harder, though not impossible, to use MVCC in building namespaces. The other reason lies in the way programmers modify them, While the contents of refs are typically modified by manipulating data as the program runs, the contents of vars in a namsepace are almost always modified during program development where the vast majority of the time the programmer wants the change to be seen system wide and immediately.

It's worth noting that there are alternatives to namespaces for storing your functions in cases where you need coordinated updates of multiple functions. It is reasonable, if you need attomic upgrades, to store your **functions in a ref and upgrade your program using dosync.** This way you can have MVCC semantics for functions that need them and keep the update-in-place semantics of namespaces everywhere that does not need coordinated upgrades.

Comment: That's a good idea - sometimes I would like to have Erlang-updateable running processes - but far from always.

Comment: About putting fns in refs - that sounds super interesting! One could build a custom namespace system... I just wonder to what extent would Clojure's interfere with it.

Comment: not at all. there would be a slight lookup cost when invoking a function that would be very similar to calling a function by invoking the var that contains it (#'+ 1 2 3) vs. (+ 1 2 3). Both work, the first is slower though it lets you redefine + more widely. In this case you would call function like (@+ 1 2 3).

Answer (score 1):

Code loading, in its very nature, is an operation that can be completely arbitrary - loading a namespace can trigger all sort of side effects, so it isn't suitable to be put into transactions.

Anyway, I think some improvements could be made to the current loading mechanism: for example,  within a call to `ns`, `require`, etc, all current vars could be listed, as well as all the vars that are being added because of the call; if the call to `ns`/`require` fails, all the vars in the latter list would be removed.

Note that such an approach would require to serialize calls to `ns`/`require`, as opposed to the current mechanism which is concurrent. I don't think there is a strong case for concurrent loading anyway.